# When Can a Set Family be Considered as a Local Base?

Tags: general-topology

Suppose $\mathcal{A}$ is a subset family on $X$. And we denote all finite intersection of $\mathcal{A} $ as $\bigwedge_f \mathcal{A}$, all arbitrary union as $\bigvee \mathcal{A}$. We say $\mathcal{A} $ is a topological base, if $\mathcal{A} $ is a base of some topology on $X$. Then we know that

> $\mathcal{A}$ if a topological base iff $\bigcup\mathcal{A}=X $, and $\bigwedge_f \mathcal{A} \subset \bigvee \mathcal{A} $.

In this case, $\mathcal{A} $ is a base of $\tau(\mathcal{A})=\bigvee \bigwedge_f \mathcal{A} =\bigvee \mathcal{A} $. And I have similar question about local base:

> If $\forall U\in\mathcal{A}, x\in U $, then when Can $\mathcal{A} $ be considered as a local base at $x$ of some topology $\tau$ on $X$?

My conjecture is that it holds iff $\bigwedge_f\mathcal{A} \subset \bigvee \mathcal{A} $. Is that true? And What is the exact topology?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hausdorff nhood axioms

$B_x$ base for x when $B_x$ not empty subset P(S), x in $\cap$B_x, 
for all U,V in $B_x$ some W in $B_x$ with W subset U $\cap$ V

for all x,y,
if $B_x$ base for x, $B_y$ base for y,
(y in U in B_x implies some V in $B_y$ with V subset U)
then
B = $\cup${ B_x | x in S } base for S
proof
if U in $B_x$, V in $B_y$, z in U $\cap$ V
then some A,B in $B_z$ with A subset U, B subset V
some W in $B_z$ with W subset A $\cap$ B subset U $\cap$ V
Thus U $\cap$ V is a union of sets from B.

Comment: Can you give a proof of these facts?

Comment: See revision @NiacrosisHermit